# how to solve class not found exception in connecting android to MYSQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am trying to make a connection between android and my database on the WAMP server and when i run the application an exception occur why is that happen? and how I can solve it? I searched a lot over the net and I reviewed the code more times and when I run the php script it works successfully and return the data but the exception still exist

this is my code

**city.PHP**

```php
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass");
mysql_select_db("Deal");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from City where Name like 'R%' ");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

**City.java**

```java
public class City extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    parseJSON();

}


void parseJSON()
{
    String result = "";
    String x = "";
    InputStream is=null;
//http post
try{
ArrayList nameValuePairs = new ArrayList();
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/city.php");
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try{
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
result=sb.toString();
}catch(Exception e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}
//parse json data
try{
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json_data=null;
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
{
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getString("City_ID")+", name:    "+json_data.getString("Name"));
}
}
catch(JSONException e){
Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
}
}
```

**logcat**

```
03-18 22:12:21.553: W/dalvikvm(491): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.JSON/com.JSON.JSONexActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.JSON.JSONexActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.JSON-2.apk]
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1739)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.JSON.JSONexActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.JSON-2.apk]
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1730)
03-18 22:12:21.583: E/AndroidRuntime(491):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you tell us what exception you're getting?

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with the exception.

Comment: class not found exception , if you want i can post the log cat

Comment: i look on the log cat , the exception is class not found , how i can solve it ?

Comment: please help me , this is my first time of connecting android application with MYSQL and its very important for me to understand it since iam working on android application based on the connection with remote databse

Comment: Please post the stack trace. If you take the time to read questions that have received answers in the `android` tag on StackOverflow, those that have exceptions usually include the stack trace. Bear in mind that beyond whatever this problem is, your code has no chance of working, as I am quite confident that you are not running a PHP server on your Android device, which is what `http://localhost/city.php` says.

Comment: iam  initialy testing it on the emulater and i tried the  10.0.2.2  instead of local host as i read in some tutorials  to solve this probleb but the exception still exist

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a class named `com.JSON.JSONexActivity` in your project, apparently, and something is trying to start that activity.

Comment: i really dont have or created this class , what is the solution?

Comment: @user1134612: Check your manifest to see if there is an `<activity>` element that references `com.JSON.JSONexActivity`. If there is, either fix it to point to some activity that you really "have or created", or get rid of the `<activity>` element entirely.

Comment: its solved , thanks , but Unfortunately  another kind of exception occur                                                             03-18 22:48:07.053: E/log_tag(619): Error in http connection java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in authority at index 15: http://10.0.2.2 /city.php
03-18 22:48:07.053: E/log_tag(619): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 22:48:07.053: E/log_tag(619): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of